# QGIS processing load memory layer with specific name

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I have a simple QGIS plugin and I use processing algorithms from my models.

Now I want to load my export from processing in my QGIS project that I do easy with `runandload` but I can't to define name that show me an default name how to load memory layer with my name?

```
outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_4=processing.runandload('qgis:fieldcalculator', outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_3['OUTPUT_LAYER'],'newnew',2,50.0,0.0,True,'left(\"TOP_KOIN\", strpos(\"TOP_KOIN\" ,\' \')-1)',"memeory:layer")
```

And if I need that memory layer to continue my script for example to do something else how to take ?with memory name? or like this `outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_4`?

**update**

```
if result:
    selectedLayerIndex = self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndex()
    selectedLayer = layers[selectedLayerIndex]
    print selectedLayer
    #calc='C:/Users/saran/Desktop/qq/calc.shp'
    outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_1=processing.runalg('qgis:fieldcalculator', selectedLayer,'trid',1,10.0,0.0,True,'$id',None)
    load_it1 = QgsVectorLayer(outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_1['OUTPUT_LAYER'], 'tid', 'ogr')
    outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_2=processing.runalg('qgis:fieldcalculator', outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_1['OUTPUT_LAYER'],'area',0,10.0,3.0,True,'$area',None)
    load_it2 = QgsVectorLayer(outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_2['OUTPUT_LAYER'], 'area', 'ogr')
    outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_3=processing.runalg('qgis:fieldcalculator', outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_2['OUTPUT_LAYER'],'perimetre',0,10.0,3.0,True,'$perimeter',None)
    load_it3 = QgsVectorLayer(outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_3['OUTPUT_LAYER'], 'perimetre', 'ogr')
    outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_4=processing.runandload('qgis:fieldcalculator', outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_3['OUTPUT_LAYER'],'newnew',2,50.0,0.0,True,'left(\"TOP_KOIN\", strpos(\"TOP_KOIN\" ,\' \')-1)',None)

    load_it4 = QgsVectorLayer(outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_4['OUTPUT_LAYER'], 'new', 'ogr')
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(load_it1)
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(load_it2)
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(load_it3)
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(load_it4)
    my_output1 = processing.getObject(outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_1['OUTPUT_LAYER'])
    my_output2 = processing.getObject(outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_2['OUTPUT_LAYER'])
    my_output3 = processing.getObject(outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_3['OUTPUT_LAYER'])
    my_output4 = processing.getObject(outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_4['OUTPUT_LAYER'])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may continue using the memory layer by loading it as an *object*. Before doing this, you need to know how the output from the algorithm is called, so typing these lines in the Python Console:

```
import processing
processing.alghelp('qgis:fieldcalculator')
```

you will see that the output's name is `OUTPUT_LAYER`:

```
ALGORITHM: Field calculator
    INPUT_LAYER <ParameterVector>
    FIELD_NAME <ParameterString>
    FIELD_TYPE <ParameterSelection>
    FIELD_LENGTH <ParameterNumber>
    FIELD_PRECISION <ParameterNumber>
    NEW_FIELD <ParameterBoolean>
    FORMULA <ParameterString>
    OUTPUT_LAYER <OutputVector>


FIELD_TYPE(Field type)
    0 - Float
    1 - Integer
    2 - String
    3 - Date
```

This means that you will be able to use it if you add a new variable and call it in this way:

```
# change 'my_output' name as you want
my_output = processing.getObject(outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_4['OUTPUT_LAYER'])
```

By now, you are ready to do something with it.

**EDIT**

From a more general point of view, I would use this code for accomplish both the tasks described in the question:

```
# see the using of 'runalg' instead of 'runandload' and the using of 'None'
outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_4=processing.runalg('qgis:fieldcalculator', outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_3['OUTPUT_LAYER'],'newnew',2,50.0,0.0,True,'left(\"TOP_KOIN\", strpos(\"TOP_KOIN\" ,\' \')-1)',None)

# the following for loading the previous output in the Layers Panel with a custom name
load_it = QgsVectorLayer(outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_4['OUTPUT_LAYER'], 'type here the name you want', 'ogr')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(load_it)

# change 'my_output' name as you want
my_output = processing.getObject(outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_4['OUTPUT_LAYER'])

# by now, 'my_output' will be the object to use for calling the layer returned by 'qgis:fieldcalculator' for further operations.
```

Comment: that is to get this layer or to take name ?

Comment: @jessiejes please, see the edits. I didn't test it, so let me know if it works for you.

Comment: `NameError: global name 'QgsVectorLayer' is not defined` what  import I miss ?

Comment: @jessiejes, try: `from qgis.core import *`

Comment: thax for help your code look very nice but I have again error AttributeError: FieldsCalculator instance has no attribute '__getitem__' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  `File "C:/Users/user/.qgis2/python/plugins\mypl.py", line 209, in run
    load_it4 = QgsVectorLayer(outputs_QGISFIELDCALCULATOR_4['OUTPUT_LAYER'], 'new', 'ogr')
AttributeError: FieldsCalculator instance has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: I have update my code

Comment: @jessiejes try using processing.runalg instead of processing.runandload: the error should be related to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58073/discussion-between-jessie-jes-and-mgri).

Comment: realy that is good help thanx you work fine now come on chat thnx again